# What is the best way to manipulate a raw email message in PHP (change headers, etc)?

Tags: php, parsing, email

What is the best way to manipulate a raw email message in PHP (change headers, etc)?

I want to make some simple changes, such as changing the Reply-To, formatting the subject, etc.

I can easily do this with regular expressions.  However, email is complicated and fragile and I know this is likely to break from something I haven't thought of.

Functions like Mailparse exist to *read* raw mail, but I cannot find a standard extension to *change* raw email.

Perhaps I should use Mailparse to help make sure I am reading the mail correctly before setting regexps to make changes.

Comment: not clear on what you are doing, is the mail that has already arrived on your server? sending mail? hacking email parsing through the network

Comment: @Dagon- A couple of separate email functions.  One function is a mail distribution list where the email arrives "from" one of the members of the list, but must be updated to show "from" a generic address in order for Amazon SES to send it out to all members, with the original address placed on the Reply-To.

Comment: i wouldn't call that updating, that is one mail in to the system an a new one out. You don't 'edit' in transit that would break the headers in cause a number of potential problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pear database provides a package, [Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/docs) that does exactly what you need.

You can install the package using [Pyrus](http://pear2.php.net/PEAR2_Pyrus) by running the following command:

```
php pyrus.phar install pear/Mail_Mime
```

The package provides an [excellent example](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php) demonstrating how a message can be created.

The package does not seem to support loading an existing raw message and manipulating it, but as you mentioned in your question, you can use Mailparse to extract the relevant information and then use that information to reassemble the message with Mail_Mime.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to leave the message intact and just make the changes directly to the one or two fields.  I'm a bit worried that, for example, 'almost broken' messages will be fully broken by taking them apart on my server, re-assembling them, and passing them through.  And also that some extra features that non-standard clients add to email might get broken (such as special thread markers by some email clients).  I'll accept the answer though, this is the way I'm going to go forward with!

Comment: you don' want to do that. you want to create a new message.